# Expected value of right half of binomial distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ that is distributed in $[-n/2,n/2]$ according to a binomial distribution centered at $0$. Now suppose I define a new random variable $Y = \max\{0,X\}$. What is the expected value of $Y$?

Comment: I never heard about binomial distribution centered at $0$ before, and the support is an interval, could you please write the probability density function of it? i think this is reall interesting problem

Comment: X is the number of heads after flipping $n$ coins, minus $n/2$. So just shift the binomial distribution to the left by $n/2$. Then define Y as above.

Comment: Note that $X=S-\frac12n$ where $S$ is binomial $(n,\frac12)$. By the central limit theorem, $$\frac{2S-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{2X}{\sqrt{n}}$$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $Z$ hence, when $n\to\infty$, $$E(Y)=E(\max(X,0))\sim c\sqrt{n}$$ with $$c=\frac12E(\max(Z,0))=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ There might be no exact formula for $E(Y)$ valid for fixed values of $n$, except for small values of $n$.